# Java Service Wrapper classpath ordering from Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, java-service-wrapper

So I understand that we can have a [deterministic classpath order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793054/maven-classpath-order-issues) from Maven POM. But how can I use this in my Java Service Wrapper configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the example in the link below, use the maven appassember plug-in to generate your jsw scripts.
Then whenever you add a new dependency in your pom and rebuild your app, your jsw script will be re-generated with the new dependency.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage_jsw.html

Comment: appassembler-maven-plugin doesn't support 64-bit JSW nor (I think) wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp

Comment: Although I never mention 64bit or WrapperJarApp in the question, to be fair. So I will up-vote the answer, but not accept it.

Comment: in the end I accepted the answer; despite the fact it doesn't help me in my particular situation, it is a feasible solution.