# How to automatically set the JRE_CONTAINER on top of all others dependencies in Eclipse.classpath?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I want to modify *automatically* the order on which `classpathentry` are written by the Maven Eclipse plugin. Is there a way to do that?

I want to do that for two reasons.

**First reason**: in my application, the interface `org.w3c.dom.Node` is provided by several third-party libraries (for XML processing), as well as the JDK (1.6). However, the version of `org.w3c.dom.*` classes provided by these libraries are quite old compared to the JDK. For example, the method [`Node.getTextContent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) does not exist there.

Running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on my project will place these library *before* the JDK container in the `.classpath`, using this method in Eclipse will result in a compilation error. So the idea is to put this line:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
```

at the beginning of the `.classpath` file.

**The second reason** (less important) is when I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, it always set my `src/test/*` packages before `src/java/*` ones, which bothers me a little (yes, I know that in TDD we develop tests first, but still...)

---

Technical information: Java 1.6, Maven 2.2.1, Eclipse plugin 2.8

---

*Edit:* There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793054/maven-classpath-order-issues) that could look similar to mine, but it did not help me as it only deals with the order for third-party dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [Maven classpath order issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793054/maven-classpath-order-issues). I can confirm that the 2.9 plugin has fixed this issue (or allows you to [futz with the config](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/myeclipse-mojo.html)).