# Java: Which of multiple resources on classpath JVM takes?

Tags: java, resources, jvm, classpath, loading

If I have multiple files of the same name on classpath (e.g. I have multiple `.jar` with `log4j.properties`), what are the rules JVM follows to chose one?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It is specified by the order in which the resources (i.e. usually jar files) are specified using `-classpath` option. Resources 'earlier' on the classpath take precedence over resources that are specified after them. This can be also set in the manifest file of your application and then you don't need to provide `-classpath` option. You may want to check [these articles](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) on how to work with manifest files.

The exhaustive description of "how classes are found" can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html), where the section on **JAR-class-path Classes** describes the logic of JAR-files searching.

Comment: If I use Maven, does that mean it's de-facto random? Setting classpath in MANIFEST.MF wouldn't work when testing (jars are taken from local repo)

Comment: Since Maven 2.0.9, this can be handled, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793054/maven-classpath-order-issues).

Comment: Any official documentation that confirms that `Resources 'earlier' on the classpath take precedence over resources that are specified after them.`?

Comment: The answer has been updated with a link to official documentation that describes the logic of class-path searching.

Comment: In addition to all that has been said, you can use `ClassLoader.getResources(String name)`. It returns all classpath resources with the given name, in the same order as described in the link provided in the answer. Useful if you need to load all of them.

Comment: How about `-jar`? for getting same name file

Answer (score 8):

The ClassLoader determines where a resource will be located (taken from ClassLoader JavaDoc):

> The ClassLoader class uses a delegation model to search for classes and resources. Each instance of ClassLoader has an associated parent class loader. When requested to find a class or resource, a ClassLoader instance will delegate the search for the class or resource to its parent class loader before attempting to find the class or resource itself. The virtual machine's built-in class loader, called the "bootstrap class loader", does not itself have a parent but may serve as the parent of a ClassLoader instance.

So wherever in your code Class#getResource or Class#getResourceAsStream is called, this happens (taken from Class.java)

```
public java.net.URL getResource(String name) {
    name = resolveName(name);
    ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader0();
    if (cl==null) {
        // A system class.
        return ClassLoader.getSystemResource(name);
    }
    return cl.getResource(name);
}
```

ClassLoader.java:

```
public URL getResource(String name) {
    URL url;
    if (parent != null) {
        url = parent.getResource(name);
    } else {
        url = getBootstrapResource(name);
    }
    if (url == null) {
        url = findResource(name);
    }
    return url;
}
```

where ClassLoader#findResource is actually to be overwritten by the ClassLoader implementation. This implies that the behavior is different on an application server, a TomCat or if you are running from a jar file, it depends on the ClassLoader implementations of the environment you are currently in.

[Here](http://littletutorials.com/2008/03/26/locating-resources-in-java/) is an example that you may use to trace what's going under the hood in your particular case.

Comment: True, it's classloader-dependent, but since I am using Java SE with standard classloaders, the other answer applies.

Comment: This should add what happens when the usual URLClassLoader is used, with multiple jars/directories.

Answer (score -1):

I am contributing a proven case that if classpath is, say, all jars in a folder, and you want to prioritize one (or some) of them, this does not work:

Windows:

```
bin/prioritized.jar;bin/*
```

Linux:

```
bin/prioritized.jar:bin/*
```

It appears that the first path bin/prioritized.jar is ignored just because the second one with a wildcard includes it in its own scope. This is what effectivelly breaks the specified order of classpaths.

Therefore, in order to have multiple resources prioritized (tested on Java 10.0.1), you need to put them in non-overlapping scopes and then they will work.