# How can I tell which specific version of JUnit IntelliJ is using?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've started working on a large project where the IntelliJ environment has already been set up.  The environment includes JUnit, and I can successfully run unit tests.  I've seen screens where I can specify the usage of JUnit 3 or JUnit 4, but how can I determine which specific JUnit is being used to run my tests, e.g., JUnit 4.11?

I have already tried "Open Module Settings".  When I look at the "Dependencies" tab, I don't see anything relating to JUnit, although I can run JUnit tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Which jar is used?**

When you run JUnit from IntelliJ, the very first line of the console output displays your classpath.  You can use Ctrl+F to find any "junit" references.

junit-rt.jar is a helper library that JetBrains might have written.  By opening the jar as an archive with 7-zip, you will find that the only package inside it is under com.intellij

According to [Java: Which of multiple resources on classpath JVM takes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644440/java-which-of-multiple-resources-on-classpath-jvm-takes) the first reference to junit.jar is the one you will use.

---

**What version is that jar?**

Once you know which jar is being used, there are a number of ways to find the version.  One is to use this code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16729507/1405720

```
import junit.runner.Version;

System.out.println("JUnit version is: " + Version.id());
```

Another method might be to open up the jar as an archive and see if you can figure it out from there.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for the JUnit libraries that are shipped with IntelliJ have a look at the corresponding jars in the lib/ directory of your Intellij IDEA installation.

For more information on this have a look at the online documention:

- http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-testing-libraries.html
- http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/testing.html

Comment: I've looked at those pages, and I've looked at the module dependencies in IDEA.  For some reason, I am not seeing anything to do with JUnit, although I can run JUnit tests.  I am editing my question to be more explicit.

Comment: @kc2001 - when you run JUnit tests in IntelliJ, you can see the java parameters in the first line of the console output. In this line there's a classpath reference to JUnit (..JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar in my case). It was added by Intellij and is unrelated to module dependencies.

Comment: @Vic Thanks for that.  I feel so ignorant.  Now that I know where junit-rt.jar is, how do I determine the version of it?