# What happens, if two similar jars with different names are added to class path?

Tags: java

If two jars with same content(say jarA , jarA_old ) are added into the class path of the working jar (i.e inside the manifest file of the main jar, which has both jarA and jarA_old in its library folder) . 
Then, which Jar will be considered when a class inside them is called or imported??

JarA has this in its manifest:

```
Build-Date: Fri, 18 May 2012 12:28:40
Build-Environment: x86 Windows XP 5.1
Build-Number: 5
```

JarA_old this in its manifest:

```
Build-Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2011 06:34:39
Build-Environment: x86 Windows XP 5.1
Build-Number: 4
```

exept this all other details are similar..

Comment: You got my curiosity tingling. I wanna know too.

Comment: It would be dependency clashes.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale - It might do.  Or it might work just fine.

Comment: @StephenC ya but usually it don't works, for eg. Hibernate or any framework related projects. And I appreciate your comment, you are right too.

Answer (score 1):

The ClassLoader will try to find the classes in all the jars of the classpath, in order. As soon as it finds it in a jar, it loads it from this jar.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html):

> Specification order
>
> The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is important.
>   The Java interpreter will look for classes in the
>   directories in the order they appear in the class path variable. In
>   the example above, the Java interpreter will first look for a needed
>   class in the directory C:\java\MyClasses. Only if it doesn't find a
>   class with the proper name in that directory will the interpreter look
>   in the C:\java\OtherClasses directory.

Answer (score 0):

see [Java: Which of multiple resources on classpath JVM takes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644440/java-which-of-multiple-resources-on-classpath-jvm-takes), it searches the jars in the order as they are listed. The first found match is used.