# ClassNotFoundException even though jar tvf shows the 'missing' class

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, maven-shade-plugin

Having a perplexing issue when I run a spark application via a deployed jar (built by maven shade plugin) in non-local environments.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:96)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:314)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:108)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:105)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
    at mypackage.SansORMProvider.get(SansORMProvider.java:42)
    at mypackage.MySansORMProvider.get(MySansORMProvider.scala:15)
    at mypackage.MyApp$.main(MyApp.scala:63)
    at mypackage.MyApp.main(MyApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:83)
    ... 13 more
```

The reason this is perplexing is because the following is in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The shade plugin has no configurations referencing this postgres dependency or any pattern that would match it.

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactSet>
                                    <excludes combine.children="append">
                                        <exclude>org.apache.spark:*:*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:*:*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </artifactSet>
                                <filters>
                                    <filter>
                                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </filter>
                                </filters>
                                <relocations>
                                    <relocation>
                                        <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                        <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.google.common</shadedPattern>
                                    </relocation>
                                    <relocation>
                                        <pattern>io.netty</pattern>
                                        <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.io.netty</shadedPattern>
                                    </relocation>
                                    <relocation>
                                        <pattern>okhttp3</pattern>
                                        <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.okhttp3</shadedPattern>
                                    </relocation>
                                    <relocation>
                                        <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                                        <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.fasterxml.jackson</shadedPattern>
                                    </relocation>
                                    ]
                                </relocations>
                                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Spark dependencies (as requested):

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-tags_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

In the output from the maven command building the jar, I can see `[INFO] Including org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.1 in the shaded jar.`

And when I run `jar tvf myShadedJar.jar | grep postgres` I can see the missing class.

One weird thing that may be relevant is when I actually unzip the jar with `jar xf` theres no org/postgresql folder.  Yet, when i `unzip` the jar it's there.

What might be the problem?  How do I confirm it?  And is it expected that the exploded jar is missing the org/postgresql folder?

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot or any other framework doing custom class loading?

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to write `java tvf myShadedJar.jar | grep postgres` and not `tar tvf myShadedJar.jar | grep postgres`?

Comment: @dan1st other modules in the project use google guice (not sure if that even does custom class loading) but not this one.

Comment: Was meant to be `jar` not `java`.  Fixing

Comment: Where does "`User class threw exception:`" come from, i.e. what wraps the `ClassNotFoundException` in a `RuntimeException`? Since this is not a message of ordinary Java exceptions, which usually look like "`Exception in thread "..." ...`". Perhaps a few more stacktrace lines would give valuable information too. Please add the POM declarations of the `maven-shade-plugin` to your question.

Comment: Let's see the full pom configuration of the maven-shade-plugin please. BTW @GeroldBroser I believe the exception is wrapped by Apache Spark. See here: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html

Comment: It is a spark application, yes.  @GeroldBroser I've added what you asked for.  Let me know if I'm missing anything else.

Comment: Is the spurious  ] in the config also in your project?

Comment: It is.  I'll remove and rebuild.  Is it expected that there is no org/postgresql  folder when I extract the jar?

Comment: I would expect that to be there, if the shade plugin unzips all .jar files and puts them in one big directory structure. Another question: which versions of Maven and the shade plugin are you using?

Comment: This is the only shade configuration in your and all your parent POMs, is it? Because "[_Why Does My Second Shade Include The Results Of The First Execution?_](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/faq.html)".

Comment: Do your Spark declarations look like in [the page _Adriaan Koster_ linked](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html) in one if his comments? I.e. do they have `<scope>provided`?

Comment: @GeroldBroser The dependency is the one in the question above.  It is not a spark dependency and has scope compiled

Comment: Another note: if I `unzip my.jar` I do see the class file.  But `jar xf` doesn't produce it.  Why is that?

Comment: According to your now updated stacktrace it begins at `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster:680`. Please add the `org.apache.spark` dependencies of your POM to the question, so we can see which versions you're using.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Updated with the spark dependencies.  Version is 2.4.3

Comment: [Your last update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68985780/revisions#rev-body-a6ae05ae-ad02-42fd-b1b2-6ca9aa5413c2) leading to "_when I actually unzip the jar with `jar xf` theres no org/postgresql folder.  Yet, when i `unzip` the jar it's there._" changes things. If you supply the complete POM (with possible sensitive information anonymized) I can create a project here to see whether I can confirm this behaviour and maybe find the reason for it. I'd need the JDK and Maven version you use, too.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I'm trying to reproduce an isolated version of this so I don't have to give you the very complex, many-pom structure I have.

In the meantime, I noticed the `jar xf` command is breaking on `java.io.IOException: license : could not create directory
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:1045)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:981)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:311)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)`

Comment: That would seem a permission problem on the file system. Please make sure the process you are starting has write permission on the directory you start it in

Comment: Could it be there is already a Postgres dependency provided by the Spark ecosystem, which clashes with your own?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Good idea! If the one that is provided by the Spark runtime system comes earlier in the classpath _and_ is a version that doesn't have the class in it... see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6644467/1744774): "_Resources 'earlier' on the classpath take precedence over resources that are specified after them._". Still remaining question is the `jar x` vs. `unzip` behaviour. But if the former is the reason of the `ClassNotFoundException` issue that may be unrelated.

Comment: Another interesting tidbit.  The following shows the 'missing' class is present the line directly before the exception:

`val cl = getClass.getClassLoader
val classesInPackage = ClassPath.from(cl).getTopLevelClassesRecursive("org.postgresql").toArray().mkString(", ")`

Comment: What's on the line causing the exception then? at mypackage.SansORMProvider.get(SansORMProvider.java:42)

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with exactly same issue migrating our spark application from AWS EMR 5.24.1 to 5.33.0. After several weeks of regular attempts to find a way out I realized eventually that HikariCP package from our uber-jar is not used during the execution. It became evident when I excluded HikariCP from the fat jar and the error didn't change though I expected that it will complain that HikariCP is not found.
It turned out that EMR 5.33.0 has *HikariCP-java7-2.4.12.jar* in multiple lib folders and this package is being used during runtime (instead of the one in the uber jar).
I merely removed all occasions of this package from both master and core nodes and this fixed the problem.
I hope this helps to somebody who is frustrating with similar issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You save me. I was lost in the jungles of shading and what not.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Based on new info from OP, not likely this is the answer.**

It looks like you have run into this issue: https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/2324

> Unfortunately - shaded jars represent a challenge. In the cases when
> the dependent library that is "shaded" contains a pom.xml in the
> META-INF directory (i.e. was built by maven or uses the maven plugin
> for gradle) - then we can extract information and detect the
> dependency. However, in the case of commons-fileupload they do not
> have a pom.xml in the META-INF (not entirely sure what build system
> they use). As such, dependency-check will not be able to identify the
> dependency. The situation is unfortunately rather bleak for shaded or
> uber jars (actually - its worse for uber jars). Even several of the
> commercial products have difficulty with this.

You could copy the file explicitly from your project into the shaded jar (e.g. by putting a copy of the jar file in your src/main/resources directory).

Or you could create a sub module in your maven project which contains this jar (and others which  might suffer from the same problem). Then add the sub module as a dependency and let the shade plugin include it.

Comment: The [Spark page](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html) you linked in one of your comments to the question declares all Spark dependencies with `<scope>provided`. It's very likely that `provided` artifacts do not have a `pom.xml` in it. I recommend to use [`install:install-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) or [`deploy:deploy-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) prior to building, i.e. creating the Fat JAR.

Comment: cont'd: 1) That's the cleanest and the _Maven way_. 2) There's no need for explicit copying then. 3) There's no need for creating an extra project then.

Comment: Sorry can you explain how this relates to my problem?  Your quote is from a project called DependencyCheck.  Are you saying spark uses the same mechanism and it can't see it?

Comment: I've tried the submodule method previously and it did not work.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I'm including the dependency with the compile scope.  It is not a spark dependency.

Comment: @b15 You wrote in a comment to the Q: "_It is a spark application, yes._". Don't you have `org.apache.spark` dependencies in your POM then?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I do have spark dependencies in my pom and they do have the provided scope but I guess I'm confused because the dependency in question is not one of those.

Comment: @b15 Please add the complete stacktrace to your Q, so we can see where it all begins.

Comment: To determine if the problem I describe in my answer is actually there in your case, check if the dependency 'org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.1' has a pom.xml in it. If it does, then there is a different issue causing your problem.

Comment: When i explode the org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.1 jar I do see a pom, yes.