# How to convert ogg file to wav using Java?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, speech-to-text

I search through Github and Google, but not found a good solution.

background:
I'm writing a Telegram bot and want to transcript user's voice message to text using Microsoft's speech-to-text java sdk, the sdk only accept wav files, so I need to first transform ogg files to wav files.

I want to find a solution to convert ogg file to wav using Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java ogg to wav conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387380/java-ogg-to-wav-conversion)

Comment: that thread seems suggesting using old utils
https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper I am going to try this.

Comment: When looking for an answer on Stackoverflow, I choose the answer that has more votes and is marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I used ffmpeg https://www.ffmpeg.org/ to transform first, it works. Installation of ffmpeg required to run this code

```
            String fileName = file.getName();
            String wavFileName = fileName + ".wav";
            String cmd = "ffmpeg -i " + fileName + " ./" + wavFileName;
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                p.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```