# Maven: how to override dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

My situation is a bit strange:

Dependency with artifact id: yyy in the pom (see below) has dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

So the problem is I need to use the 3.1.0 version in the current module because it has extra functionality:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried the exclusions tag and dependencymanagement tag explained in the example on the page: [Maven: how to override the dependency added by a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937195/maven-how-to-override-the-dependency-added-by-a-library)

It does not work. I have also read and tried the 3 examples in this article: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

It also did not work. So what I did was to re-order my pom dependencies so that the 3.1.0 goes before the one with artifact yyy and I was happy it worked I built successfully a clean install. My happiness was short lived because after a clean install the pom re-ordered itself and the 3.1.0 was automatically re-ordered back below the yyy. Which means the next build will use 2.5 again and fail.

My pom structure snippet is as below:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>xxxx.xxx.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Comment: guess this might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793054/maven-classpath-order-issues

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by: ' It does not work'....

Comment: adding the dependency yourself (either as a direct dependency, or within the dependency management) should do the trick. If it doesn't I guess there is something else bothering you

Comment: @khmarbaise i mean its picks up the version 2.5 version of javax.servlet-api

Comment: Than you need to show the full pom file apart from that it could come as transitive dependency by another dependency ...

Answer (score 3):

> My happiness was short lived because after a clean install the pom
>   re-ordered itself and the 3.1.0 was automatically re-ordered back
>   below the yyy. Which means the next build will use 2.5 again and fail.

Note that the `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api` has to be included in a WAR but only in a standalone JAR that includes and bootstraps a servlet container.
If you build a standard WAR you have to use the dependency provided by the server. So the dependency should be declared with the `provided` scope.

> I have tried the exclusions tag and dependencymanagement tag explained
>   in the example on the page: Maven: how to override the dependency
>   added by a library

`dependencyManagement`  will be helpless here as the issue is related to a dependency you include outside the `dependencyManagement` element.
But using the `exclusions` option in the `dependency` declaration is the right way. It should exclude the `2.5` version of the `javax.servlet-api` artifact if used in this way :

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>xxxx.xxx.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        <groupId>javax.servlet-api</groupId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If the problem persists it means that the dependency is probably pulled by another dependency.
Some hints that generally help to discover that :

- check that you don't use WAR overlay feature. But not likely here as you retrieve only 1 version of the dependency
- use `mvn dependency:tree` on the WAR project to inspect all pulled dependencies.
  To ease the readable you can also filter in this way :
  `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=javax.javax.servlet-api`

Answer (score 0):

The solution below has ignored the version 2.5 and so it is working. However i don't know what it means. Does it remove other dependencies? Please interpret what the asterix in  groupId and artifactId mean in simple english. I want to know the risks because i am using a multi module system where there to many nested dependencies in other dependencies. I will continue to research as of now but if anyone can explain please do. Thanks

```
    <dependencies> 
      <dependency>
         <groupId>xxxx.xxx.xxxx</groupId>
         <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
         <exclusions> 
            <exclusion> 
              <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  // this works or 
              <groupId>*</groupId> // this works
              <artifactId>*</artifactId> // this part was a mandatory *
            </exclusion> 
         </exclusions> 
      </dependency> 
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```